# How to change the opacity of a node?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, d3-force-directed

Scenario:

On mouse hover on a particular node, I am trying to highlight that node and all its interconnected nodes by changing the opacity and all the other nodes should be blurred.

Expectation: 
On mouse hover on a node, Opacity of that node and all its interconnected nodes should be 1 whereas the other nodes should be blurred using lesser opacity.

Existing functionality:
It does not work as expected when i hover on any node for the first time. But from the second time onward It is working properly.

Please refer the jsfiddle: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vivekhegde99/ujae9w2c/16/)

```
var nodeElements =  g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "nodes")
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(graph.nodes)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("r", 60)

  .attr("stroke", "#fff")
  .attr('stroke-width', 21)
  .attr("id", function(d) { return d.id })
   //.attr("fill", function(d) {return color(d.id)}) 
     .attr('fill', function(d, i) { return 'url(#grad' + i + ')'; })
     .on('contextmenu', function(d){ 
        d3.event.preventDefault();
        menu(d3.mouse(svg.node())[0], d3.mouse(svg.node())[1]);
    })
      .on('mouseover', selectNode)
      .on('mouseout', releaseNode)
  .call(d3.drag()
    .on("start", dragstarted)
    .on("drag", dragged)
    .on("end", dragended));


function selectNode(selectedNode) {
  var neighbors = getNeighbors(selectedNode)
        nodeElements.transition().duration(500)
        .attr('opacity', function(node) {
        return setOpacity(node,neighbors, selectedNode);
   })
   .attr('r', function(node) {
        return getNodeRadius(node,neighbors);
   });
   nodeElements.attr('fill', function(node) {
        // send selectedNode to your getNodeColor
        return getNodeColor(node,neighbors,selectedNode);
    })
   textElements.style('font-size', function(node) {
    return getTextColor(node, neighbors)
  })
  textElements.attr('opacity', function(node) {
        return setOpacity(node,neighbors, selectedNode);
   })

  linkElements.style('stroke', function(link) {
    return getLinkColor(selectedNode, link)
  })
}

function releaseNode() {
nodeElements
.attr('r', 60)
.attr('fill', function(d, i) { return 'url(#grad' + i + ')'; })
 .attr('opacity', 1);

linkElements.style('stroke', 'grey');
textElements.attr('opacity','1');
}



 function setOpacity(node, neighbors, selectedNode) {
        if (Array.isArray(neighbors) && neighbors.indexOf(node.id) > -1) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0.3;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is quite simple: don't use `attr` to set the opacity, use `style` instead:

```
nodeElements.transition()
    .duration(500)
    .style('opacity', function(node) {
        return setOpacity(node,neighbors, selectedNode);
    })
```

Here is the code with that change only: https://jsfiddle.net/uye24zjn/

#### Explanation

The explanation is a bit more complicated. Firstly, have in mind that you never set any previous opacity, be it using `attr` or `style`.

When you transition the opacity D3 uses a getter to retrieve the original value, applying the respective method (`attr` or `style`). And here comes the problem: because you never set any opacity using the `attr` method, the previous value using `attr` as the getter is `null`. However, using `style`, the value is `1`:

```js
const circle = d3.select("g")
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 50);

console.log("The opacity value using 'attr' as a getter is: " + circle.attr("opacity"))
console.log("The opacity value using 'style' as a getter is: " + circle.style("opacity"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <g transform="translate(150,75)"></g>
</svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

The consequence is that D3 will try to transition from `null` (zero) to `1`, and you'll see the circles disappearing at the begin of the transition. As a demo, hover over the circle:

```js
const circle = d3.select("g")
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 50);

circle.on("mouseover", function() {
  d3.select(this).transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("opacity", function() {
      return 1
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <g transform="translate(150,75)"></g>
</svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

The issue happens only on the first mouseover (just like your code), because after hovering over the circle the opacity is set as an attribute, and there will be no more `null` when `attr` is used as a getter.

As a general rule, use `attr` to set **attributes**, and use `style` to set the **styles**. In other words: use `style` to set anything that you would do using a CSS file.

Comment: Thank you so much for precise explanation @Gerardo. Now i have understood how this works.